# How can I tell when my html page has loaded

Tags: java, browser, swt

How can I tell when my html page on loaded in my swt browser?  Is there some sort of event I can listen to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ProgressListener` to it.  It has a method called `completed` through which you receive notifications that a page has been fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You need handle the method changed() from LocationListener(http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/ProgressListener.html) and test whether event.top is true